# something is wrong google crawler. please

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

```
# 뉴스 크롤링.py

#######################################'사용후핵연료' 키워드 검색##################################################
import sys, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas import DataFrame
import time
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

sleep_sec = 0.5

wb = Workbook()

# User-Agent를 입력해주세요.
headers = {'User-Agent' : '________________'}

query = 'spent nuclear fuel'
yesterday = (datetime.today() - timedelta(1)).strftime("%Y.%m.%d")

def news_crawling():
    
    service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)


    print('브라우저를 실행시킵니다(자동 제어)\n')

    news_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={0}&tbm=nws&source-news]'.format(query, yesterday)
    browser.get(news_url)
    time.sleep(sleep_sec)
    

    print('\n크롤링을 시작합니다.')

    #####동적 제어로 페이지 넘어가며 크롤링
    news_dict = {}
    idx = 1
    cur_page = 1
    news_num = 1000000

    while True:

        table = browser.find_element("xpath",'.//div[@data-hveid="CBAQAA"]')
        li_list = table.find_elements("xpath",'.//li[contains(@class="vJOb1e aIfcHf Hw13jc"]')
        area_list = [li.find_element("xpath",'.//div[@class="mCBkyc y355M ynAwRc MBeuO nDgy9d"]') for li in li_list]
               
        for a in area_list[:min(len(area_list), news_num-idx+1)]:
            n = a.find_element("xpath",'.//div[@role="heading"]')
            n_url = n.get_attribute('href')
                    
            try:
                img = a.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'img#dimg_').find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img')
                img = img.get_attribute('src')
                
            except:
                img = " "
                    
            news_dict[idx] = {'Title' : n.get_attribute('title'),
                            'url' : n_url,
                            'thumbnail': img}
            
            idx += 1
            
            
        try:
            next_btn = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a#pnnext')
            next_btn.click()
        
            cur_page +=1 
          # pages = browser.find_element("xpath",'//div[@class="sc_page_inner"]')
          # next_page_url = [p for p in pages.find_elements("xpath",'.//a') if p.text == str(cur_page)][0].get_attribute('href')
            pages = browser.find_element("xpath",'//table[@class="fl"]')
            next_page_url = [p for p in pages.find_elements("xpath",'.//a') if p.text == str(cur_page)][0].get_attribute('aria-lable')

            browser.get(next_page_url)
            time.sleep(sleep_sec)
            
        except:
            print('\n브라우저를 종료합니다.\n' + '=' * 100)
            time.sleep(0.7)
            browser.close()
            break

        ########################################################여기까지 수정 완료################################################################

# 엑셀파일 추출        
    print('데이터프레임 변환\n')
    
    news_df = DataFrame(news_dict).T

    folder_path = os.getcwd()
    xlsx_file_name = '{}_{}.xlsx'.format(query, yesterday)

    news_df.to_excel(xlsx_file_name, index=False)

    print('엑셀 저장 완료 | 경로 : {}\\{}\n'.format(folder_path, xlsx_file_name))
    
news_crawling()
```

this is my code. I use it on Korean website and it works well. But after I modified it for google search, it wouldn't work.

I want to search something on google and then get the news titles into a xlsx file.

I before used it in Korean website, so I changed the part below

```
 table = browser.find_element("xpath",'.//div[@data-hveid="CBAQAA"]')
        li_list = table.find_elements("xpath",'.//li[contains(@class="vJOb1e aIfcHf Hw13jc"]')
        area_list = [li.find_element("xpath",'.//div[@class="mCBkyc y355M ynAwRc MBeuO nDgy9d"]') for li in li_list]
```

and when I run the code, it only gives me an empty xlsx file.

can anyone help with this please? I would be so appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def get_url(query: str, min_date: str, max_date: str) -> str:
    return f'https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&tbm=nws&source-news&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:{min_date},cd_max:{max_date}'


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
service = Service(executable_path="path/to/your/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

yesterday = (datetime.now() - timedelta(1)).strftime("%m.%d.%Y")

driver.get(get_url('spent nuclear fuel', yesterday, yesterday))

url_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#rso a')
title_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a div[role="heading"]')
thumbnail_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#rso a>div>div:first-child img')

workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active
page = 1
while True:
    print(f'Current page: {page}')
    url_web_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(url_locator))
    title_web_elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(title_locator))
    thumbnail_web_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(thumbnail_locator))

    titles = [title.text.replace(',', '.') for title in title_web_elements]
    urls = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in url_web_elements]
    thumbnails = [thumbnail.get_attribute('src') for thumbnail in thumbnail_web_elements]
    
    for data in zip(titles, urls, thumbnails):
        news = {
            'title' : data[0],
            'url' : data[1],
            'thumbnail': data[2]
        }
        worksheet.append(list(news.values()))
    try:
        page += 1
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#pnnext'))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
workbook.save(f'google_news_{yesterday}.xlsx')
driver.quit()
```

Output is xlsx file `google_news_11.10.2022.xlsx`
[image]

In the `get_url` function, you can pass a range of dates for which the news will be displayed. For example `get_url('spent nuclear fuel', 01.11.2022, 11.11.2022)`

You can also save data to `csv` using this solution:

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def get_url(query: str, min_date: str, max_date: str) -> str:
    return f'https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&tbm=nws&source-news&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:{min_date},cd_max:{max_date}'

def save_to_csv(data: list) -> None:
    with open(file='google_news.csv', mode='a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow([*data])


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
service = Service(executable_path="path/to/your/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

yesterday = (datetime.now() - timedelta(1)).strftime("%m.%d.%Y")

driver.get(get_url('spent nuclear fuel', yesterday, yesterday))

url_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#rso a')
title_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a div[role="heading"]')
thumbnail_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#rso a>div>div:first-child img')

page = 1
while True:
    print(f'Current page: {page}')
    url_web_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(url_locator))
    title_web_elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(title_locator))
    thumbnail_web_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(thumbnail_locator))

    titles = [title.text.replace(',', '.') for title in title_web_elements]
    urls = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in url_web_elements]
    thumbnails = [thumbnail.get_attribute('src') for thumbnail in thumbnail_web_elements]
    
    for data in zip(titles, urls, thumbnails):
        news = {
            'title' : data[0],
            'url' : data[1],
            'thumbnail': data[2]
        }
        save_to_csv(news.values())
    try:
        page += 1
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#pnnext'))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break

driver.quit()
```

Output is `csv` file `google_news.csv`:

```
COP27: nuclear boss doesn't expect surge in waste recycling,https://news.yahoo.com/cop27-nuclear-boss-doesnt-expect-072631885.html,"data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
UN Nuclear Chief Says Recycling Nuclear Waste 'Difficult ...,https://www.theepochtimes.com/un-nuclear-chief-says-recycling-nuclear-waste-difficult-after-biden-looks-to-fund-reprocessing-projects_4855151.html,"data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
COP27: UN nuclear chief says radioactive waste recycling is 'difficult' technology,https://www.deccanherald.com/international/world-news-politics/cop27-un-nuclear-chief-says-radioactive-waste-recycling-is-difficult-technology-1161036.html,"data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
```

Tested on `Python 3.9.10`. Used `Selenium 4.5.0`, `openpyxl 3.0.10`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!
I really appreciate it!
Is there any way that I can return your favor??
You are a legend!